# activemq-all "5.15.3" does not work with Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am updating Spring from 4.x.x to Spring 5.0.3. The project uses ActiveMQ version 5.15.3. When I try to deploy the application with the newest version of Spring I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.obtainApplicationContext()Lorg/springframework/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.detectMappedInterceptors(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:243)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 53 more
```

I noticed that ActiveMQ has Spring version "4.3.9" as a dependency. This version does not have the method "obtainApplicationContext" in "AbstractHandlerMapping" and hence the problem. Is there a way exclude the Spring libraries from the activemq-all bundle?

Comment: Which build system do you use? Maven? Gradle?

Comment: I am using Ant + Ivy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this was my problem too but I eventually got my Spring webapp deployed on TomEE to successfully connect and use ActiveMQ hosted and running internally to that Tomcat container.

I'm using Spring 5.0.3-RELEASE and activemq-client 5.15.3. I didn't need everything in the maven shaded uber jar activemq-all.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

  @Bean
  public SingleConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
      ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory)
            // See http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html why we set trusted packages
            .setTrustedPackages(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("com.mydomain", "java.util")));
    return new SingleConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
}

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
      return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue myQueue() throws JMSException {
      Connection connection = connectionFactory().createConnection();
      connection.start();
      Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Queue queue = session.createQueue("message-updates");
      return queue;
  }
}

@Component
public class MyQueueImpl implements MyQueue {

  @Inject
  private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  @Inject
  private Queue myQueue;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
   jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(JmsTemplate.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT);
  }

  @Override
  public void enqueue(Widget widget) {
      jmsTemplate.send(myQueue, new MessageCreator() {
          @Override
          public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
              return session.createObjectMessage(widget);
          }
      });
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Widget> dequeue() {
    Optional<Widget> widget = Optional.empty();
    ObjectMessage message = (ObjectMessage) jmsTemplate.receive(myQueue);
    try {
        if (message != null) {
            widget = Optional.ofNullable((Widget) message.getObject());
            message.acknowledge();
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new UncategorizedJmsException(e);
    }

    return widget;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Matthew K above. I found that too. ActiveMQ-all have packed a version of spring (currently that 4.x version) inside.  There are some none-backwards compatible changes between that and spring v.5.  I came across a new method in one of the other spring classes myself.  It can cause this kind of issue (no such method exception in my case).
I had this issue with activeMQ 5.15.4 and spring 5.0.7.  In the end I solved it with using the finer grained jars instead.  I had to use all these: activemq-broker,activemq-client,activemq-pool,activemq-kahadb-store,activemq-spring