# activemq endpoint in spring boot ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to move to spring boot to get cleaner dependencies in an application using Camel and ActiveMQ. I used to have `activemq` endpoint configurated in an XML file:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
<property name="brokerURL" value="${gatewaybroker}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start"  destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig"
   class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
</bean>

<!-- create a Camel ActiveMQ component -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>

    <!-- if we are using transacted then enable CACHE_CONSUMER (if not using XA) to run faster
         see more details at: http://camel.apache.org/jms
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
    -->   
</bean>   
</beans>
```

and then have routes being called using that ActiveMQ endpoint:

```java
from("activemq:queue:configuratelearningmodule")
    .routeId(routeid)
    .autoStartup(false)
    .process(       
        new Processor(){                    
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
//                         etc....
```

Now I created a spring-boot app and trying to migrate progressively. I didn't find a way to get access to an endpoint "activemq" with the autoconfigured spring-boot activemq so I tried to keep my xml configuration file. After all, I'm ok to configure myself the activemq endpoint and I am only using spring-boot to not bother about versions conflicts between all elements (jpa/hibernate, spring, camel, activemq, mqtt, etc...)

However I receive this message:

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. 
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializerPostProcessor':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'beanFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
Error loading class [org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent] 
for bean with name 'activemq' defined in class path resource [jmsconfig.xml]: 
problem with class file or dependent class; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/impl/HeaderFilterStrategyComponent
```

On Camel 3.1 migration page, they tell `activemq-camel` has been moved to `camel` so I'm tweaking my `pom.xml` with `camel-activemq` component but that doesn't change anything.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>        

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea how to get that activemq endpoint working in spring-boot ?

Comment: I opted adding individual jars. one of the answer [activemq-all-5-15-3-does-not-work-with-spring-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652986/activemq-all-5-15-3-does-not-work-with-spring-5)

Answer (score -1):

you could try to use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Greets

Comment: adding the activemq dependency, ```java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(java.lang.Object, java.util.function.Supplier)'
    at org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService.getFieldType (FormattingConversionService.java:123)
```

Comment: Give https://start.spring.io/ a try where you define what you need in your project, generate it and then add your missing dependencies and your code part